# How does Apache file system work?

Tags: apache, filesystems, elgg

I'm using Elgg - open source social networking framework for one of my projects. I have to customize it a lot, the problem is I don't understand how its filesystem works!

The project is located in **localhost/elgg** folder.

Now, inside a browser, there are links to **/register/index.php** and **/blog/index.php**. But inside actual project directory (**/elgg**) on my server there are none named **/register** or **/blog**.

How is that even possible? How do I find the folders?

Comment: What version of Elgg are you using?

Comment: The latest one (1.8). I still can't figure out where all the files are.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @emaillenin's answer:
Elgg does use URL rewriting.. most elgg page views are done by the main page handler found in

```
<installdir>/engine/handlers/page_handler.php
```

which calls the `page_handler($handler, $page)` function, defined in

```
<installdir>/engine/lib/pagehandler.php
```

Of course, you'll have to dig deeper than that to find what generates register/index.php content -- one place to start looking is for `elgg_register_page_handler()` calls..

for example, the blog index is registered into elgg's system via `elgg_register_page_handler('blog', 'blog_page_handler');` in

```
<installdir>/mod/blog/start.php
```

The same file also contains the `blog_page_handler()` function...

If you're developing a plugin, it's worth looking at Elgg's [PageHandler](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/Controllers/PageHandler) wiki entry

Answer (score 0):

I think Elgg uses URL rewriting by itself which redirect **/register/index.php** and **/blog/index.php** to different files in the system.

Check if there are anything in the .htaccess file or elgg might be redirecting the pages internally.